# Initialize form using the dictionary from request.POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to have a 'save' form option which will save the data to database to Draft table. (So I don't mix it with the submitted data).

When the user click submit, I create a draft and fill it with the POST data.

```
 Draft.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
 draft.data = post_to_json(self.request.POST)
 draft.save()
```

Post_to_json does the following

```
def post_to_json(post):
    dictionary = {}
    for key in post.keys():
        data = post.getlist(key)
        dictionary[key] = data
    return json.dumps(dictionary)
```

it saves the POST as it is so if email was a input field and skills where a multicheckbox in POST there is `{"email": ["my@mail.com"], "skills": ["01", "02", "03", "04"]}` and post_to_json saves it that way. (If I would just dump it I'd get `{email": "my@mail.com", "skills": "04"}` so some skills would be lost(Not to mention that it wouldn't initialize properly in the form)).

Now I have a problem how to initialize the Form when the user returns and want to continue in the process.

I tried to do:

```
def get_initial(self):
    draft_uuid = self.kwargs.get('uuid')
    draft = Draft.objects.get(uuid=draft_uuid)
    return json.loads(draft.data)
```

But then in the browser I have prefilled `["my@mail.com"]` instead of just `my@mail.com`.

How does Django work that it can actually prefill the form just fine when I do MyFormClass(request.POST) but it fails when I try to convert the POST to dictionary and then use it the same way?

So my goal is to load the data from a dictionary to a form so it's prefilled in the browser.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data back into {field: value} format and set as form initial wherever you instantiate the form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#initial

Why can't you do this -

```
data =  user.get_initial()  # Giving you the json format
mcb_fields = ("skills",)   #If you have more such fields, write their name here
init_data = {}
for key, value in data.iteritems():
     if key in mcb_fields:
        init_data.update({key :value})  # check if you have to convert each value to int or if it accepts string (this is in str format)
     else:
        init_data.update({key :value[0]})
form = SomeDraftForm(initial =init_data)
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't work because my data looks like: `{'email': ['my@mail.com']}` so when I do it that way I have `['my@mail.com']` in the form..... I also tried to hack it like `if len(value) == 1: return value[0]` but I doesn't work then for multicheckbox when only 1 answer is ticked.